# How to make a efficent undo-implementation in python

Tags: python, undo

I want to make an undo-implementation in a Programm with GUI more efficent:
At the moment every time you create an action, a deepcopy of my Dataobject will be generated. The problem: The Dataobject is veeery big, so the deepcopy takes about 2 seconds...

I thinking about integrate the command-pattern, but it seems to be veeery much work to this in an efficent way. Is there any other good solution to implement an undo/redo feature for changes of objects?

Comment: Do you use a GUI Framework? Qt e.g. has Undo already implemented...

Comment: yeah, I'm using wxPython, but I read somewhere, that wx itself doesn't implement undo/redo :/